# Юзание кнопочек на сайте с помощью winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

Подскажите пожалуйста, как нажимать кнопочки на сайте программным путем через компонент webbrowser?

Comment: Опять? При чем здесь Win API?

Comment: Сори, я имел в виду winforms

Comment: Вы же, кажется, уже нашли  `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("buttonId").InvokeMember("click");`

Comment: в "buttonId" мне нужно просто подставить название нужной кнопки? Допустим есть кнопка на сайте Купить, то тогда будет так `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("Купить").InvokeMember("click");`

Comment: Используя "View Source" или F12 браузера, найдите эту кнопку и посмотрите значение аттрибута `id`. `<button type="submit" id="btnBuy">Купить</button>`

Comment: Пробую через хром ctrl+shift+c - выбираю нужную кнопку, там есть теги input, значения value но id нигде нету.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
{
   string attrValue = element.getAttribute("value");
   if (attrValue == "Купить")
   {
        element.InvokeMember("click");
   }
}
```

Comment: Не работает;( я сделал кнопочку, что бы нажимая на неё - нажималась кнопочка на сайте, жму кнопочку ничего не происходит

Comment: Ребят, помогите, по-прежнему не разобрался.

Comment: @КириллКирьянчиков Пора Вам выкладывать Ваш код. "сделал кнопочку ... жму кнопочку" - может означать что угодно. Укажите хотя бы ссылку на страницу, которой Вы пытаетсь управлять.

Comment: На форме компонент веб браузер и моя кнопочка, я хочу нажимая на свою кнопочку - нажимать кнопочку на сайте. У меня не получается ;(  


    `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var elements = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input");
            foreach (HtmlElement element in elements)
            {
                if (element.GetAttribute("value") == "Купить")
                {
                    element.InvokeMember("click");
                }
            }
        }`

Comment: Ставьте breakpoint на строчку с `var elements = ...`, и идите по шагам (F10) глядя на значение `attrValue`.

Comment: В цикл программа даже не заходит. Пробегает мимо.

Comment: Укажите ссылку на страницу, которой Вы пытаетсь управлять.

Comment: Там нужно регистрироваться, что бы Вы смогли увидеть эти кнопочки, которые я пытаюсь нажать. Возможно как-то нашу беседу перенести в соц. сеть или любое удобное для Вас место, где бы я могу покидать скринов или описать проблему более детально?

Comment: Какой бы я тег не указал, в elements ничего не заносится, поэтому и по циклу бегать не хочет.

Comment: Отбой, нужно было просто разбить на фреймы еще, такова структура того сайта. За ответ спасибо, помогло!